# How to derive the profile page URL from a username for a number of social networks

Tags: facebook, flickr, google-plus

I'm writing an app which asks the user for the usernames for multiple social networks. e.g. Twitter, Facebook, Google+.

I would then like to be able to send clickable links in an email to a given user. The links should resolve to the profile pages for the given user.

Currently this is an iOS app.

For a service like Twitter, this is trivially easy: everyone knows their usernames, and it is a simple case of string concatenation to get the username.

For Google Plus, string manipulation is out of the question.

For Flickr and Facebook, there are vanity URLs, but it's not straight forward.

I don't mind doing any heavy lifting on a server, but I'm asking the question to make sure I'm not missing a trick.

My question is this:

- given a username, is there a way of deriving the profile page?
- what API calls should I be looking for?
- is there a service already to do this?
- is this a real question?

Answer (score 1):

For facebook get JSON from `http://graph.facebook.com/<username>` and see the `link` value

Flickr has an API call `flickr.people.findByUsername` http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.people.findByUsername.html

Google Plus has API too, e.g.

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/userId`

https://developers.google.com/+/api/

Answer (score 1):

Google+ doesn't have the notion of usernames.  The old Google Profiles product did, of the form `https://profiles.google.com/{username}`.  For users that had old-style profiles and have activated Google+, this will redirect to their `https://plus.google.com/ID` profile.  That said, the vast majority of Google+ users don't have these old usernames, so it's probably not worth trying that route.

The recommended approach to get a user's profile URL is to send the user through an OAuth flow with the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me` scope, then call [people.get](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get) with a userId of "me", and pull the profile URL of the response.

Comment: Yah. Was hoping to avoid an OAuth flow. :(